# I am getting strange MS Access error

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working on a very old, very poorly written MS Access application for a client.  I am getting a query error that is stumping me as to how and where to find the root cause.  See the query attached and the error.

I have never seen a query error with a ".[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRPt9.png)" at the end.  I have been looking through the various referenced queries for a field "1" but cannot find it.

[image]

Any Ideas??

Comment: One of those data sources in the `FROM` clause is a query which is based on a crosstab query named `Drug Inventory Data_Crosstab QOH card directs curr month`  Once upon a time, that crosstab result set included a column whose header was named `1`, but now does not include that column.  Open that crosstab query in Datasheet View and see what columns are available.  Is there a reasonable substitute for `1` which can work in the query which uses the crosstab?

Comment: You use formatnumber([avgof1]/[qty]/[a],1). I think this 1 should be a `0` or a `#`? I may be wrong. What do you think?  I would also have used format() function, I didn't realise this formatnumber() was even a function in access ha